# Customize BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv

So I want to customize rows in order to get this.

[image]

I want to see the details above focused item but I'm not sure which approach I need to take.Can anyone help me this one ?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment, I'll have to put an answer.

I don't know if I understand your question entirely, but you want when focused on an item like video 1 or video 2, to show some details.

First approach is to make text views in the places where you want to show the data and initially set their visibility to GONE, and the on click on the item set them to VISIBLE.

The other approach I can think about is using alert dialog, as on click to open a popup window with the details.

The first approach is more to your liking and description in the question but I liked to give you some other choice too.

If I haven't totally understood the question, tell me more and I will edit my answer regarding the details.